# Check if parent of current node is last on its level

Tags: xslt, xpath

Given xml like that:

```
<grand-parent>
  <parent/>
  <parent>
    <child/>
  </parent>
  <parent/>
  <parent>
    <child/>
  </parent>
</grand-parent>
```

and xsl like that:

```
<xsl:template match="child">
  some stuff
</xsl:template>
```

is it possible to check inside the `some stuff` section that we've reached that last parent and do actions with the child of that last parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try testing `parent::*[not(following-sibling::*)]`, or add a template to match it specifically, like `match="parent[last()]/child"`.